# How can I perform More like this (mlt) queries using NEST?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Are mlt queries even supported in NEST? and if they are not supported, is there a workaround to perform them?

Answer (score 0):

They are:

Either as a query type on `_search`:

http://nest.azurewebsites.net/query/mlt.html

or as on `_mlt` operation on it's own see the unit tests here:

https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/tree/master/src/Nest.Tests.Unit/Core/MoreLikeThis